# Insert image from database (BLOB) Echo

Tags: php, mysql, database, image, echo

I am trying to insert a image which belongs to an employee profile.

My code:

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM employeeTbl where department='aarhus';";
    $rows=$conn->query($sql);
    foreach ($rows as $row){
        echo '<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="min-height:225px;overflow:hidden; margin-top:30px">;
?>

<img src="getimage.php?aid=<?php echo $row["aid"]; ?>" />

<?php
        echo '<h2 style="margin-top:-10px">'.$row["name"].'</h2>';
        echo '<i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;<a href="mailto:'.$row["mail"].'">' .$row["mail"].'</a>';      
        echo "</div>";
    }
?>
```

My getimage.php code is:

```
<?php
     $conn = mysql_connect("mysql34.unoeuro.com", "user", "pass");
     mysql_select_db("dbname") or die(mysql_error());

     if(isset($_GET['aid'])) {
          $sql = "SELECT image FROM employeeTbl WHERE aid=" . $_GET['aid'];
          $result = mysql_query("$sql") or die("<b>Error:</b> Problem on Retrieving Image BLOB<br/>" . mysql_error());
          $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
          header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
          echo $image;
     }
     mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

My database the aid is Auto increment.

Hope you can help me - or find a better solution to this.

Comment: You shouldn't use the mysql_ functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5, and removed in PHP 7.0. You should use mysqli_  functions (mysqli_query, for example), and it requires two parameters. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Or use PDO:: functions

Answer (score 0):

In the first step mysql is deprecated and i suggest using to mysqli functions.

About creating image i suggest following code:

```
$data = base64_decode($image);
$im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
if ($im !== false) {
     header('Content-Type: image/png');
     imagepng($im);
     imagedestroy($im);
}
```